# Why does the istitle() string method return false if the string is clearly in title-case?

Tags: python, string

Of the `istitle()` string method, the Python 2.6.5 manual reads:

> Return true if the string is a titlecased string and there is at least one character, for example uppercase characters may only follow uncased characters and lowercase characters only cased ones. Return false otherwise.

But in this case it returns false:

```
>>> book = 'what every programmer must know'
>>> book.title()
'What Every Programmer Must Know'
>>> book.istitle()
False
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method title() doesn't mutate the string (strings are immutable in Python). It creates a new string which you must assign to your variable:

```
>>> book = 'what every programmer must know'
>>> book = book.title()
>>> book.istitle()
True
```

Answer (score 8):

`book.title()` does not change the variable `book`. It just returns the string in title case.

```
>>> book.title()
'What Every Programmer Must Know'
>>> book             # still not in title case
'what every programmer must know'
>>> book.istitle()   # hence it returns False.
False
>>> book.title().istitle()   # returns True as expected
True
```

Comment: OK, that is what I was missing! Thanks. The documentation actually does say that .title() returns a version of the string.

Answer (score 3):

Probably because you are still calling istitle() on the original book.

Try book.title().istitle() instead....

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

```
print book
```

after you do `book.title()`. You will see that `book` hasn't changed.

The reason is that `book.title()` creates a new string. The name `book` still refers to the original string.